# How to make smoother lines?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bezier

I'm trying to make a simple drawing application and I've already implemented the Bezier formula and am also using Unity's Post-Processing stack for anti-aliasing, but but my lines still aren't very smooth.

I'm assuming this is a result of the "mouse noise" so even small movements cause the lines to become wobbly. But what bothers me most are the sharp turns, which I've circled in red, shouldn't really be appearing. I add a new point whenever the mouse has moved 0.1f away from the previously added point in the list. Then, once I have three points, I apply Bezier's formula which creates 20 smaller lines to create the curve. [Fullscreen 1920 x 1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX75z.jpg)

So, how can I smooth out/remove noise from my lines?
Are there are line smooth algorithms I could employ? Or settings or plugins I could alter and use?

Script if anyone needs it:

```
public LineRenderer linerend;
List<Vector2> mainPoints;    
List<Vector2> points;
public int smoothness = 10;
private int pt = 0;


public void UpdateLine(Vector2 mousePos)
{
    if (mainPoints == null) {
        points = new List<Vector2>();
        mainPoints = new List<Vector2>();
        SetPoint(mousePos);            
        return;
    }
   
    if (Vector2.Distance(mainPoints.Last(), mousePos) > 0.1f)
        SetPoint(mousePos);
}

void SetPoint(Vector2 point)
{
    mainPoints.Add(point);
    pt++;
    if (pt == 3)
    {        
        DrawLine(mainPoints[mainPoints.Count - 3], mainPoints[mainPoints.Count - 2], mainPoints.Last());            
        pt = 0;   
        
    }     

}


private Vector2 CalcuateBCurvePoints(float t, Vector2 p0, Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2)
{
    float a = 1 - t;
    return a * a * p0 + 2 * a * t * p1 + t * t * p2;
}

private void DrawLine(Vector2 p0, Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2)
{       
    for (int i = 0; i <= smoothness; i++)
    {
        float t = i / smoothness;
        Vector2 point = CalcuateBCurvePoints(t, p0, p1, p2);
        points.Add(point);
        linerend.positionCount = points.Count;
        linerend.SetPosition(points.Count - 1, point);
    }       
    
}
```

Comment: Try changing your smoothness to a float. In your `i / smoothness` calculation you're dividing two integer values which will return another integer value (rounded down) and then that result will be cast to a float to fit it in your `t`. So `t` will be `0` for all iterations except the last, then it will be `1`

Comment: Also each bezier only takes into account the new points, so the seperate bezier lines you generate won't always connect smoothly together

Comment: @Knoop thanks for the suggestion, I think it helped make my lines somewhat smoother but the sharp turns are still there. Do you happen to know any alternatives to the Beizer formula if there isn't anything I can do to reduce noise?

Comment: Use Catmull-Rom spline to interpolate your points, then draw the cubic Bezier curves. If there is an API to draw a cubic Bezier curve directly such as the path object in SVG, use it and avoid drawing multiple line segments on your own.

Comment: Yes Catmull-Rom definately seems like the way to go. But as I said in my second comment I think your biggest problem at the moment is that you're generating separate bezier curves (every 3 new points create a disconnected curve). If you want to generate a single line that seems smooth you have to build the line as you go along. Lets say you know points p0, p1, p2, and p3. At this point don't draw the curve between all these points but use the Catmull-Rom to draw a smooth the line between the points p1 and p2. Then when point p4 arrives you can draw p2 to p3 using p1, p2, p3 and p4...etc